# Attribute [Emission] [number field] is not visible because the object can not be on the lookout

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am in trouble to encounter the following phenomenon in unity2018. 
In Unity5 and Unity2017, when the check box of `[Emission]` is checked in the material setting, a numerical input field is displayed, and the intensity of light was able to be controlled, but in Unity2018 if you check the box, you will not see the numeric input field.

For this reason, I cannot make the unleash light object by the previous technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This numerical input field has been moved in the color picker itself.

You can control the intensity value from there by clicking on the **[HDR]** box near the `[Emission]` checkbox.

See this screenshot :

[image: Color Emission]

Comment: Thank you for the polite explanation. I solved it safely in my environment. It was a blind spot for me that the GUI changed.

Comment: @StorchW Nice to hear ! Welcome to SO. If this answers your question, don't forget to click on the green tick to mark it as accepted :)